# jquery selectors - id problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I made a form with ajax email validation. My problem is that I need to have more than 1 email input field. The code in jquery that I wrote works only with one. I don't want to use the solution with copy and paste changing the id because it is not efficient and also the amount of email fields is not constant.

This is my js file:

```
// 0 - email not valid
// 1 - email valid
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ClientEmail_0").focusout(function() {
        // span with loader gif
        $("#ajax_status_0").css('display','inline');
        // span with the results
        $("#email_ajax_result_0").css('display','none');
        var $email = $("#ClientEmail_0").val();
        $.post("/reservations/reservations/ajax_check_email/",{data:{Client:{email:$email}}},function(data) {
            $("#ajax_status_0").css('display','none');
            if (data == 1) {
                $("#email_ajax_result_0").attr('class','ajax_success');
                $("#email_ajax_result_0").text('Email is available');
            } 
            if (data == 0){
                $("#email_ajax_result_0").attr('class','ajax_error');
                $("#email_ajax_result_0").text('You are already our client. Proceed with the reservation.');

            }
            $("#email_ajax_result").css('display','inline');
        });
    });
});
```

This is my view:

```
<?php
for($i = 0 ; $i < $this->params['nr'] ; $i++){
    echo $this->Form->input('Client.'.$i.'.email', array(
        'label'=>$this->Html->tag(
            'span', 
            $html->image("icons/ajax-loader.gif", array(
                "alt" => "loading",
            )), 
            array(
            'id' => 'ajax_status_'.$i,
            )), 
        'div'=>'IconMail clearValue',
        'after' => $this->Html->tag(
            'span', 
            '', 
            array(
            'id' => 'email_ajax_result_'.$i,
        )),
    )); 
} 
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why you need to use IDs over classes.

Comment: Yes, I don't need to use so many IDs, just one ID and the rest as classes. I will change this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this -

First give common class name say mail to your basic trigger element (in your example ClientEmail_0 one)

then use the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mail").focusout(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        // span with loader gif
        $("#ajax_"+id).css('display','inline');
        // span with the results
        $("#email_"+id).css('display','none');
        var $email = $("#"+id).val();
        $.post("/reservations/reservations/ajax_check_email/",{data:{Client:{email:$email}}},function(data) {
            $("#ajax_"+id).css('display','none');
            if (data == 1) {
                $("#email_"+id).attr('class','ajax_success');
                $("#email_"+id).text('Email is available');
            } 
            if (data == 0){
                $("#email_"+id).attr('class','ajax_error');
                $("#email_"+id).text('You are already our client. Proceed with the reservation.');

            }
            $("#email_"+id).css('display','inline');
        });
    });
});
```

edit your view to this -

```
<?php
for($i = 0 ; $i < $this->params['nr'] ; $i++){
    echo $this->Form->input('Client.'.$i.'.email', array(
        'label'=>$this->Html->tag(
            'span', 
            $html->image("icons/ajax-loader.gif", array(
                "alt" => "loading",
            )), 
            array(
            'id' => 'ajax_ClientEmail_'.$i,
            )), 
        'div'=>'IconMail clearValue',
        'after' => $this->Html->tag(
            'span', 
            '', 
            array(
            'id' => 'email_ClientEmail_'.$i,
        )),
    )); 
} 
?>
```

My basic idea in above example is that the id of the basic trigger element should be present in every further element's id.

for example:

if main trigger element id is say ClientMail
then the further elements id becomes

email_ClientMail

ajax_ClientMail

ie the first part is constant and further part is the main elements id.

it will work even when there are an unknown number of elements.

Try it out and let me know.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the solution. It works exactly as I wonted. I tried to change the IDs to classes but I think that for this I need one generic trigger (div) so I left it like this.

Comment: @Michal: glad i was able to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Change your focusout action to a standalone javascript function.  Then use the [$.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) function in jquery to bind each field to the new function.  Use the "this" variable `$(this).css()` to select the element in your function.

```
$("#ClientEmail_0").bind('focusout', yourNewFunction);
$("#ClientEmail_1").bind('focusout', yourNewFunction);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for help. I tried to use your solution but I had some problems and before I fixed them another solution appeared. Also I didn't know how automatically bind the function with all the email fields (their number changes).